# Can i get Ipv6 internet when using google's public DNS if my ISP doesn't provide Ipv6?

Tags: ipv6, ip-address, google-public-dns

I mean it doesn't seem to work so I guess not :/

Is there like a Google IP address that I can use or sth?

Comment: Teredo protocol allows to access IPv6 nodes over IPv4 networks. It must be installed and connected to your network interface.

Answer (score 0):

Native IPv6 connectivity must be provided by your ISP. Your first step should be to contact your ISP and ask if IPv6 service is available.

It may be that you simply need to upgrade your cable modem, *DSL router, or privately owned Wi-Fi router, to use IPv6 service that your ISP already provides. Older equipment might not support IPv6, or you might have some device which has had IPv6 turned off, that you can turn back on.

Failing that, you can obtain an IPv6 tunnel service from a few places, such as [tunnelbroker.net](https://tunnelbroker.net/), who will provide an IPv6 tunnel and a routed /48 for you to play with and [learn](https://ipv6.he.net/certification/) about.